# Generate 7 digit number similar to original number in PHP

Tags: php, random

I would like to generate 7 digit number that is very similar to the original randomized number in PHP.

The purpose is: the original randomized number simulates the telephone number that is used in a sound game where users identifies the correct number while listening to the audio.

Using loop

```
$original_randomized_number=rand(1000000,9999999);
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
$generated_telephones[$x] = rand(1000000,9999999);
}
```

to generate 3 random telephone numbers works, but it is too simple to identify the correct number.

F.e. the original randomized number 9876543 - the desired result similar to - 9865742, 8896558, 9586543

Comment: *is very similar* - can you define what you mean by similar?

Comment: Yes, thank you. 3-5 digits at their respective positions remain same, 4-7 digits remain same in the number (on whatever position). If it is possible to add a pattern of difficulty (the closer the number looks, the more difficult to recognize in a sound game, imho), it would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.tehplayground.com/WJiQXDOWT5CR5SwS

```
$phone = "9876543";
function getSimilar($phone, $num) {
    $out = array();
    for( $x=0; $x<$num; $x++) {
    $new = array();
    $p = str_split($phone);
    $ctr=2;
    foreach ($p as $n) {
     $neg = rand(0,10) > 5? 1:-1;
     $n = abs((intVal($n) + ( rand(0,$ctr) * $neg)) );
     $new[] = min($n,9);
     $ctr++;
    }
    $out[]=implode("",$new); 
  }

  return $out;

}

$nphone = getSimilar($phone, 5);
echo $phone . "\n";
print_r( $nphone);
```

example output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9634999
    [1] => 7988194
    [2] => 9896724
    [3] => 8949969
    [4] => 8998434
)
```